# int64_t stored in a void pointer and then cast to a double always ends up being 0.000

Tags: c, integer, double

I am making a function that converts any number (int64_t, uint64_t, double and later also hex numbers) to a string. I wrote 3 working functions for them seperatly but now I am trying to put it in one function. I searched around a bit on how to do this in C (I am relatively new to C) and found out I can do this with void pointers. I need to do this without the C library because this is for a hobby OS I am making.

This is how I am currently doing the checks for what type of number it is:

```
const char* to_string(void* value)
{
    double val = *(double*)value;

    if (val == (int64_t)val) {
        return int_to_string((int64_t)val);
    }
    else
    {
        // double to string conversion.
    }
}
```

But when I put in an int64_t or uint64_t null pointer it always returns 0.00000, which I don't fully understand.

I have reproduced this issue in a really small code snippet:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int64_t testNum = 2390874;
    void* value = &testNum;
    double val = *(double*)value;
    printf("%f", val);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to just see the number printed, but that was not the case. I suspect I made some beginner mistake because C is new to me. Help would be much appreciated, and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: If you run it in the debugger, you'll see val gets set to an incredibly tiny number: 1.1812487069350445e-317. This will print as 0 for the default precision in printf(). Misusing pointer casts in this way will probably invoke undefined behaviour. You really don't want to be doing this.

Comment: @pmacfarlane: 1.1812487069350445e-317 is credibly tiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value 2,390,874 is not represented in the `double` format by bits that encode the number 2,390,874 in the same way as an `int64_t`.

Here is some explanation of the sample code:

> `int64_t testNum = 2390874;`

This says to encode 2,390,874 in the format used for `int64_t` and store it in memory reserved for `testNum`. Using hexadecimal to represent the bits, this puts 00 00 00 00 00 24 7B 5A in memory.

> `void* value = &testNum;`

This says to take the address of the memory reserved for `testNum`, convert it to `void *`, and store it in `value`.

> `double val = *(double*)value;`

This says to convert the address in `value` to `double *`, use it to access the memory, and interpret the bits there in the `double` format. Doing the reinterpretation this way is not defined by the C standard. However, I will explain what happens assuming your C implementation does it.

In the format most commonly used for `double`, IEEE-754 binary64, the first bit encode a sign (0 for +, 1 for −), the next eleven bits encode an exponent and one bit of the significand, and the remaining 52 bits encode the rest of the significand. (The significand is the fraction portion of a floating-point number.)

In 00 00 00 00 00 24 7B 5A, the first bit is 0, so it encodes a + sign. The next eleven bits are zero. This encodes the exponent −1022, meaning a scaling of 2<sup>−1022</sup>, and it also indicates the leading bit of the significand is 0. (The significand is the fraction portion of a floating-point representation.) The remaining bits, ending in 24 7B 5A, encode the significand 2,390,874•2<sup>−52</sup>. (The scaling 2<sup>−52</sup> is built into the format.)

Thus the number encoded is +2<sup>−1022</sup>•2,390,874•2<sup>−52</sup> = 2,390,874•2<sup>−1074</sup>, which is about 1.1812487069350•10<sup>−317</sup>.

When you format this with `%f`, it appears as “0.000000” because it is so small. If you format it with `%.99f`, it will appear as “1.18124870693504449006160973608001590543193999051572110682125774306312005276915307940719688096129009e-317” in a good C implementation.

In conclusion, you cannot test whether bits in memory represent an `int64_t` or `double` by examining the bits alone. The same bits encode different values in different types. Type information must be conveyed separately.

Comment: Thanks! So I basically need to use different functions for this exact scenario? Or can you recommend something else?